# AVR for Xcode 4?

Tags: eclipse, xcode, avr, avr-gcc, avrdude

Has anyone had success using xcode 4 as an IDE for AVR microcontrollers? Is it possible to have the same amount of integration as the plugin for eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I use Xcode 4 as IDE when writing AVR code.

But it only works as a "wrapper" for the avc-gcc command line tools. I have three Xcode targets in the project: **build** ("make all": compile only), **fuse** ("make fuse": program fuses) and **flash** ("make flash": compile and download to AVR). Just select the appropriate target and hit Cmd-B to build.

There is not much integration. I still have to edit the Makefile to set clock frequency, programmer and device model and fuse values. And if I add more .c files I also have to add the corresponding .o file to the Makefile. But at least I can do it from within Xcode.

I have created a minimal project template that will allow you to create a new AVR project in Xcode. Get the file here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1194636/AVR_Xcode4_template.zip. Extract the archive and put the Atmel AVR® folder into ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates (you might need to create the Templates folder).

Answer (score 2):

Template from second answer (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1194636/AVR_Xcode4_template.zip) works fine but with some tweaks.. You have to put these in file "makefile" in the template to be able to include multiple files in the project:

```
OBJECTS    = main.o $(OBJ)
SRC =  mynewfile.c
OBJDIR = .
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
LST = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst)
```

in SRC section you need to enter all files that are built in the project (*for example mynewfile.c*).

One more enhancement is to clear all the obj files from the project, after the linking ... Find the section main.hex in makefile and change rm -f line with following

```
    rm -f main.hex $(OBJ) $(LST) main.o
```

Other then that, everything stays the same. What i couldnt find out is how i can enable code complete for this template. If anyone knows i would appreciate the help.